# Is there a yarn command that shows the path of where all of your packages are installed?

Tags: yarnpkg

I have multiple versions of a dependency in my package (via transitive dependencies).  I know `yarn why <package>` gives some clues about why the different versions are present.

Is there a command that shows the exact path of where each package has been installed too?

(I'm curious about both yarn 1 and yarn 2)

Comment: Not sure if this helps in your situation, but I use the `which` command a lot.

Comment: The unix which command which shows you where an executable is? I don't think that will tell me where a package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a yarn command for such task. But it's fairly trivial to find out.

```
Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%/Yarn/config/global
Unix(Mac/Linux)(non-root): ~/.config/yarn/global
```

However, if you want to know the location of a module in node_modules in your project, you'll have to traverse the entire node_modules folder. In Linux, you could do something like this.

`find <<project_path>>/node_modules -maxdepth 1 | perl -wnle '/module_name/ and print'`

Comment: Hmm, I'm referring to packages installed within the node_modules tree inside the project, rather than global packages..